# how to use erase, partition and iterate together at once on vector of objects

Tags: c++, std

~ i'm learning c++ on my own~

I have a class field vector of objects that I want to iterate through and erase things that don't meet a certain condition.

myVector[0] is {obj1= val 1, obj2= val 2, obj3= val3 }
.
.
.
myVector[i] is {obj1= val x, obj2= val y, obj3= valz }

my issue is in order to pass the value to predicate function i need to access the object id and value at that index. But I don't know how to implement it so that i iterates/ increments.
Or more specifically how to I pass that key value at each index ? I'm asking for syntax help.

something like this:

```
myVector.erase(std::partition(myVector.begin(),myVector.end(), predicate(myVector[i].obj1)),myVector.end());
```

obviously there is no way for me to increment i this way.
is there a way to do this without using a for loop

Comment: You can't erase things from a vector while you're iterating it.  You can either copy the "winners" to a new vector and delete the old one altogether, or remember the indices of the ones to delete, and delete those in a separate loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts: This isn't true.  There are various ways to iterate over a vector while erasing elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, because you seem to be worried about the indexes into the vector.  If your predicate needs to look at the indexes and not just the items in the vector, that complicates things.

However, does this solve your problem?

```
#include <algorithm>

myVector.erase(
  std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myPredicate),
  myVector.end());
```

This is an example of the so-called "erase / remove idiom."  The call to `remove_if` shifts the elements you want to keep forward in the list the appropriate amount but doesn't truncate the vector.  Instead, it returns a pointer to the end of the list, which you can then pass to `erase`.

(Why can't we do this just a single call, instead of having the confusingly-named `erase` AND `remove` together?  Because `std::remove_if` is part of `<algorithm>`, which consists of generic algorithms that work on anything that supplies the right sort of iterators, whereas `erase` is special to `std::vector`.  Having a start/end pair of the right sort of iterators gives you enough functionality to do what `remove_if` does, but doesn't give you the ability to truncate the list directly.)

You can write this using a lambda if you don't want to break the predicate out into its own method.  For instance:

```
myVector.erase(
  std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(),
    [](const auto & x) { return x.obj1 <= 0; }),
  myVector.end());
```